# Compiling a C Source through javacode

Tags: java, c, gcc, gnu

I am trying to compile a C program through a javacode. I did it as follows.

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/cygwin/bin/sh -c 'gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld.exe'");

    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line, log;
    log ="\n..Input..\n";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      log+=line;
      log+="\n";
    }

    InputStream is2 = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(is2);
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(isr2);
    String line2;
    log+="\n..Error..\n";
    while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
      log+=line2;
      log+="\n";
    }
    System.out.println(log);
```

HelloWorld.exe is not created and following error message was displayed. /usr/bin/sh: gcc: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current run-time environment and invoke exec method. Here is an example:

`String cmd="C:/cygwin/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld.exe'";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

Comment: That won't help.  Read the javadoc for `exec(String)` to understand how it splits the string into arguments.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that `exec(String)` splits the string into arguments naively at the white-space characters.  You need to do the splitting for it.  write the `exec` as:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
     "C:/cygwin/bin/sh",
      "-c",
      "gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld.exe"});
```

The `exec(String)` method does not understand shell syntax such as quoting and redirection.

It might also be necessary to use a full pathname for the `gcc` command, but I doubt it.  The shell should inherit the environment variable settings from the JVM, and that probably includes a suitable `PATH` variable.

Comment: tried this...this time the error message didn't appear. Nothing was displayed on console. Also HelloWorld.exe was also not created.

Comment: Try some experiments.  1)  Try to run the command from the windows command prompt.  2) Replace "gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld.exe" with "cat HelloWorld.c" or "ls -l HelloWorld.c" or "ls -ld ."

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

rather than

```
gcc
```

say, use full path for binaries call in script.